# creating XML output in PHP

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to create an XML file output in PHP for a remote phone book on an IP Phone, here is the code i have:

```
<?php
$conn=mysql_connect("localhost","user","********");
mysql_select_db("db_name",$conn);

header("Content-Type: text/xml");
header("Connection: close");
header("Expires: -1");
?>

<YealinkIPPhoneDirectory>
<?php
$output='<YealinkIPPhoneDirectory>\n';
$sql="SELECT * from contacts ";
$rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn);
while($result=mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
    $output .= "<DirectoryEntry>\n";
    $output .= "<Name>Mobile:</Name>\n";
    $output .= "<Telephone>" . $result["mobile"] . "</Telephone>\n";
    $output .= "</DirectoryEntry>\n";
}
$output='</YealinkIPPhoneDirectory>\n';

echo '$output';
?>
```

but i get this error message:

```
This page contains the following errors:

error on line 3 at column 8: Extra content at the end of the document
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

$output
```

Comment: Try `echo $output;` instead

Comment: This page contains the following errors:

error on line 3 at column 27: Extra content at the end of the document
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

Comment: i get that error when i try echo $output;

Comment: You get what error? can't be the same...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

$conn=mysql_connect("localhost","user","********");
mysql_select_db("db_name",$conn);

header("Content-Type: text/xml");
header("Connection: close");
header("Expires: -1");

$output = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";
$output .= '<YealinkIPPhoneDirectory>\n';
$sql="SELECT * from contacts ";
$rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn);
while($result=mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
    $output .= "<DirectoryEntry>\n";
    $output .= "<Name>Mobile:</Name>\n";
    $output .= "<Telephone>" . $result["mobile"] . "</Telephone>\n";
    $output .= "</DirectoryEntry>\n";
}
$output.='</YealinkIPPhoneDirectory>';

echo $output;

?>
```

Comment: I'm now getting this : This page contains the following errors:

error on line 1402 at column 27: Extra content at the end of the document
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error. but it shows all the results it should do. not in XML format though

Comment: it just echoes as a block of HTML text

Comment: Right, I think your XML is just coming out bad as that error seems to be on the application end I'm guessing. I also removed the reference to mysql_fetch_array... I always forget that grabs both array types by default.

Comment: Also, try adding $output = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n"; as the first line of your output.. Don't forget to change the = to .= for the second line and see what you get.

Comment: tried all that - now getting error on line 2 at column 6: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document

Comment: Updated the answer, try the above

Comment: still the same thing :/ error on line 1402 at column 27: Extra content at the end of the document

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46537/discussion-between-mjayt-and-user2710234)

Comment: Looks like maybe you got it? Don't forget to mark correct if it worked to solve the output issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove this line:

```
echo '$output';
```

and replace it with this:

```
echo $output;
```

Here is a sample:

https://eval.in/96740

Note how singlequoted values are literally echoed, so you literally see `$output` as your output.